# IF statement SQL query within the SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, group-by

I have the below stored procedure which works fine.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TxCountByDatePerod`(IN `fromdate` DATE, IN `todate` DATE, IN `department` VARCHAR(20), IN `status` VARCHAR(10), IN `ipg` VARCHAR(20))
SELECT d.dept_name,
       s.service_name,
       COUNT(*) AS all_row_count
FROM department AS d
INNER JOIN service s ON s.dept_id=d.dept_id
INNER JOIN transaction_detail t ON s.dept_id=t.dept_id
AND s.service_id=t.service_id
WHERE t.tx_begin_date BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
  AND (t.dept_id = department
       OR department ='null')
  AND (t.tx_status = status
       OR status ='null')
  AND (t.pg_name = ipg
       OR ipg ='null')
GROUP BY t.dept_id,
         t.service_id
```

Above SP is written in MySQL to get the number of transactions for a given time duration, provided by a particular service of a particular department. A transactions can be 3 different transaction statuses(`tx_status` coulmn) which are completed(1), failed(-1), uncompleted(0).

What I'm trying to do is get the data for the report below.

[image]

The right now the problem is that all the status are grouped into one row. I tried the below SQL to get the data as needed but it gives out an error that the syntax is not correct.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TxCountByDatePerod`(IN `fromdate` DATE, IN `todate` DATE, IN `department` VARCHAR(20), IN `status` VARCHAR(10), IN `ipg` VARCHAR(20))
SELECT d.dept_name,
       s.service_name,
       COUNT(*) AS all_row_count,
       IF(t.tx_status = 1,
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM transaction_detail
          WHERE tx_status = 1) AS successful_tx_count
FROM department AS d
INNER JOIN service s ON s.dept_id=d.dept_id
INNER JOIN transaction_detail t ON s.dept_id=t.dept_id
AND s.service_id=t.service_id
WHERE t.tx_begin_date BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
  AND (t.dept_id = department
       OR department ='null')
  AND (t.tx_status = status
       OR status ='null')
  AND (t.pg_name = ipg
       OR ipg ='null')
GROUP BY t.dept_id,
         t.service_id
```

Please see the added line below.

```
IF(t.tx_status = 1, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction_detail WHERE tx_status = 1) AS successful_tx_count is added to the SP.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the correct syntax for using an IF statement with a select is like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `TxCountByDatePerod`(IN `fromdate` DATE, IN `todate` DATE, IN `department` VARCHAR(20), IN `status` VARCHAR(10), IN `ipg` VARCHAR(20))
SELECT d.dept_name,
       s.service_name,
       COUNT(*) AS all_row_count,
       IF(t.tx_status = 1, 
          (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction_detail WHERE tx_status = 1), 
          0 
         ) AS successful_tx_count
FROM department AS d
INNER JOIN service s ON s.dept_id=d.dept_id
INNER JOIN transaction_detail t ON s.dept_id=t.dept_id
AND s.service_id=t.service_id
WHERE t.tx_begin_date BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
  AND (t.dept_id = department
       OR department ='null')
  AND (t.tx_status = status
       OR status ='null')
  AND (t.pg_name = ipg
       OR ipg ='null')
GROUP BY t.dept_id,
         t.service_id
```

NOTE:

I just put in a default 0 value since you are doing a count but you can change that

```
IF(t.tx_status = 1
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction_detail WHERE tx_status = 1)
    ,0 -- # -- this can be anything.. you could put in NULL or whatever else if you want
  ) AS successful_tx_count
```

you can also use a user defined variable and plug that in like so

```
SET @a := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction_detail WHERE tx_status = 1);
```

and then plug the @a variable in your if statement like so

```
if(t.tx_status = 1, @a, 0)
```

See this [ARTICLE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx) for more details on the if function

Comment: +1 for the answer. The problem with this query is why does WHERE clause conditions don't apply to the sub query?

Comment: @dasun did you try using the set query with a user defined variable? Does that option work? If you want help with the whole thing i need some data to work with and test

Comment: @dasun if you would like to post more data I can try and get it working in the query.. If my answer solves your issue it would be appreciated if you could go ahead and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is your `select` statement:

```
SELECT d.dept_name,
       s.service_name,
       COUNT(*) AS all_row_count,
       IF(t.tx_status = 1,
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM transaction_detail
          WHERE tx_status = 1) AS successful_tx_count
```

Why are you using a subquery here?  I suspect that you want the "successful" count to match the same conditions (from the `where` clause) as the `count(*)`.  So, just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT d.dept_name,
       s.service_name,
       COUNT(*) AS all_row_count,
       SUM(t.tx_status = 1) AS successful_tx_count
```

Comment: the only issue I see with this is if there are rows filtered out when the table is joined.. and the OP wants a count of all rows

Comment: @JohnRuddell . . . I am actually assuming that the OP does *not* want all the rows counted.  The way the report is structured, it looks like the counts should use the same filtering logic as the rows.  I admit the OP may have something else in mind, so this assumption may be wrong.

Comment: yea I don't know for sure but i figured it was worth pointing out... still i gave you a +1 :)

Comment: +1 for the answer. SUM() cann't be applied since SUM of -1 values does not give the correct count. The problem with this query is why does WHERE clause conditions don't apply to the sub query?

Comment: @Dasun . . . I don't know what you mean by "SUM of -1" values.  The expression `SUM(t.tx_status = 1)` returns the count of the number of times that status is 1 for the rows summarized by the `group by`.